# Any faster scp or rsync?

Tags: networking, rsync, scp

How can I transfer a large file quickly, when I don't really require a secure connection?

Often I would like to copy a large file from local machine to remote machine.  The file does not already exist on remote machine.  I usually use `scp` or `rsync` (which i think might use ssh underneath *anyway*).  It can be kind of slow and I suspect it's not due to network limitations, but because it's trying to copy securely.  Using blowfish cipher doesn't improve things much, and I couldn't get null cipher to work at all.

**edit:** for the record, copying a ~75MB file took about 17 minutes, and rsync reported 78032.72 bytes/sec.  If my calculations are correct and the network is 10/100 (100,000,000 *bits*/sec) then isn't that only about 0.6% of the possible network speed?!

Comment: This [ServerFault Question](http://serverfault.com/questions/146377/why-is-my-rsync-so-slow-compared-to-pure-cp-or-even-scp) may be of interest to you. Try FTP maybe?

Comment: I think your issue is not with the encryption - I regularly get much better speeds than that using scp even over encrypted wi-fi (802.11b or g). (for what it's worth, using scp, I generally see something close to 15-16 Mbit/s under optimal conditions, several times that on a wired connection).

Comment: Is the *whole path* from the local machine to the remote machine 100Mb/s? A network path cannot transfer data between two points faster than it can across the slowest link in the path.  If you actually have a 100Mb/s path between them then are they close enough that you could just put the file on a USB stick and walk it to its destination?

Comment: I'm sure the path isn't 100Mb/s but i doubt it's as bad as 0.6% of that either.  I could use a USB stick, but that would mean.. getting the keys to the server room from the authorized person, taking down a keyboard, taking the lift to L27.. hmm and my seat is more comfortable ! :)

Comment: @digitxp Using the *file transfer protocol* to *transfer* a *file*? Who would want to do that? You must be joking!

Comment: Make sure it's not an IO issue on the remote machine.  I once spent a lot of time tracking down what I thought was a network issue only to find it was a hard disk issue.

Comment: Also check latency (ping) and check for one-way bandwidth saturation.  If a link is saturated in only one direction (say by other traffic or an asymmetric link speed) it will look on a bandwidth graph as though there is plenty to spare, but TCP connections will falter as ACK messages are delayed or dropped.  Very high latency can have similar effects.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48399/fast-way-to-copy-a-large-file-on-a-lan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [mirrordir](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mirrordir) - [more here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6564). Mirrordir is faster than rsync because it has no delta checks. However, even on their man page they claim it is dangerous command. Also, I believe is not supported anymore. 
Your pure network bandwidth test is with dd and netcat, as demonstrated [here](http://daverdave.com/node/196)

Comment: thanks - could you show me how to use `dd` and `netcat` to check bandwidth test?  i imagine it could be a huge mistake if i accidentally use dd incorrectly.. :)

Comment: Link for dd & netcat added.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/39027/easiest-way-for-fast-transfer-of-files-between-linux-servers) from serverfault.com and my reply:

If you want speed you could use netcat and tar. It will be faster than ssh, rsync, or scp on a local network where encryption is not a concern. Google "netcat tar".

#### DestinationServer

```
nc -l -p 7878 | tar -C /target/dir -xzf -
```

#### SourceServer

```
tar -cz /source/dir | nc DestinationServer 7878
```

This obviously requires that netcat is actually installed. Google "netcat tar" for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Use `bzip2` to compress the file and see if it can reduce the size to be transferred. Compression should be very effective for text files, but will not do much on JPGs or videos.

By the way, a uploading bandwidth of around 512 Kbps is very possible, if you are using a home internet connection.

Comment: You may also want to try 7zip or Rar as they have special file filters tailored to get the best compression for that particular type of file.